# Expressing product of row block matrices as matrix operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have block row matrices $A=[A_i]$ and $B=[B_i]$. How can I express $C=\Sigma_i A_i B_i$ as a matrix operation?

I imagine one could define a block transpose operator such that $A^{bT}$ is a column block matrix with rows $A_i$ so that $C=AB^{bT}$, but is there a trick to express this using common matrix operations?

Note that I can’t access the individual blocks of either matrix.